# How can I perform this Mysql query with IF condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have an existing Mysql Table with data loaded (`TblParts`)

```
Code Stock Price Location id
1     10   1000   Global  1
2     5    1500   Office  2
3     2    500    Global  3
4     1    100    Global  4
```

I have a second table with new information (`TblNewParts`)

```
Code Stock Price Location id
1    30    2000    Global 1
2    5     1000    Global 2
3    10    5000    Global 3
4    30    200     Global 4
5    40    500     Global 5
```

I need to update `TblParts` with `TblPartsNew` data

- If `Code` exists, and `Location = Global`
  then update `Stock` and `Price`
- If `Code` exists, but `Location <> Global`
  then insert record with same `Code` and distinct `Location`
- If `Code` does not exist then add it

The output of `TblParts` must be:

```
Code Stock Price Location
1    30    2000   Global 
2    5     1500   Office 
3    10    5000   Global 
4    30    200    Global 
5    40    500    Global
```

Really I don't have an idea how to perform this.

Comment: Do you have to do this using a single query or can we split it into two queries?

Comment: When you say "and Location = Global", do you mean the Location in `TblParts` or `TblPartsNew`?

Comment: The way you do this is to write a `SELECT` query that uses a `JOIN` to find all the rows in `TblPartsNew` that need to be added or merged into `TblParts`. Then use that in `INSERT INTO TblParts SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: I have to leave now, so I can't show you the exact query. But I hope that should be enough for you to make an attempt to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for response. I can use Two Querys if the result if the same!

Comment: When i Say Location = Global i mean In TblParts

Comment: i need compare by code, if i use on duplicate keys will fail because the ID are diferent in tables.

Comment: Does `TblParts` allow duplicate `Code`? If not, you can create a unique key on `Code` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will work. It doesn't have to be the primary key, any unique column will work.

Comment: I don't understand the second step, "Insert record with same Code and distinct Location". It looks like you didn't insert anything, you just kept the original row for Code = 2.